# Load a data set from local drive but pandas report this file does not exist

Tags: python, load, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to load a data set from local file into python jupyter but it says the file does not exist. What I did is the following

```
import pandas as pd
RX_df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\20130717\My School Stuff\Course\CS\QData\RX.txt',delimiter="|",nrows=20)

FileNotFoundError: File b'D:\\20130717\\My School Stuff\\Course\\CS\\QData\\RX.txt' does not exist
```

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829387/trying-to-load-file-into-python-but-it-states-that-it-does-not-exist-even-though) link and try different combination of `/`, `r`, `R`, `\\`, `\` but none of them work. Also, according to this above link, I did

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()); print(os.listdir('.'))
```

It generates

```
/home/jovyan/work/Project
['.ipynb_checkpoints', 'DataPreprocess.ipynb', 'Project.ipynb']
```

But this does not help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Well...does the file exist? `os.listdir('.')` isn't exactly helpful if the file isn't in your current directory.

Comment: Did you try `os.listdir(r'D:\20130717\My School Stuff\Course\CS\QData\)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  it says no such file or directory. But there indeed one! I am using windows, so the path I use is directly copy and paste from path from that small windows on top of the folder, I didn't type them. Is that because I am on docker?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think I found the problem, it is due to the docker. I tried to also launch anaconda jupyter directly not from docker, then my command works fine, I can load the data. But this creates another question, why it does not work on docker?

Answer (score 0):

I previously had the same issue for a file that was already .txt

I save it as apple.txt for the name when it was already a .txt file

So i rename it back to apple (without the .txt)

same for CSV files

Hope this helps others